# Storing a nested trait instance in a generic variable

Tags: generics, types, rust, traits

If I have an "outer" trait with a univeral generic type (`Collection`, below), then I can create an instance of that with an "inner" trait type (`Collection<&dyn Stringable>`). I can then use any values with that instance as long as those values implement the nested trait (`Stringable`):

```
fn main() {
    let mut vs: &mut Collection<&dyn Stringable> = &mut vec![];
    vs.add(&1);
    vs.add(&true);
    vs.add(&3);
    for v in vs.get_all() {
        println!("{}", v.string());
    }
}

trait Collection<T> {
    fn add(&mut self, v: T);
    fn get_all(&self) -> &Vec<T>;
}

impl<T> Collection<T> for Vec<T> {
    fn add(&mut self, v: T) {
        self.push(v)
    }
    fn get_all(&self) -> &Vec<T> {
        &self
    }
}

trait Stringable {
    fn string(&self) -> String;
}

impl Stringable for i8 {
    fn string(&self) -> String {
        format!("int({})", self)
    }
}

impl Stringable for bool {
    fn string(&self) -> String {
        format!("bool({})", self)
    }
}
```

However, if I implement both the outer and inner trait for a type (`Collection<i8>`), a value of that type can't be put in a `Collection<&dyn Stringable>` variable, even though the inner type of the first (`i8`) implements the second (`Stringable`). The code below gives the following error:

```
the trait `Collection<&dyn Stringable>` is not implemented for `StaticCollection`
```

Code:

```
fn main() {
    let mut vs: &mut Collection<&dyn Stringable> = &mut StaticCollection{};
    for v in vs.get_all() {
        println!("{}", v.string());
    }
}

struct StaticCollection {}

impl Collection<i8> for StaticCollection {
    fn add(&mut self, v: i8) {}
    fn get_all(&self) -> &Vec<i8> {
        &vec![1, 2, 3]
    }
}
```

Is it possible, for example, to write something like `impl Collection<&dyn Stringable> for StaticCollection`, so that the `StaticCollection` can be stored in the generic `Collection<&dyn Stringable>` variable?

Comment: The `&vec![1, 2, 3]` part doesn't compile because it tries to return a reference to a temporary. I assume you could fix that but you'd have a similar problem tying to return a `Vec<&dyn Stringable>` since [`Vec<T> is not interchangeable with Vec<dyn U>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58683548/how-to-coerce-a-vec-of-structs-to-a-vec-of-trait-objects), you'd have to create a new Vec to return it as trait objects.

Comment: There's no *general* problem with implementing both `Collection<i8>` *and* `Collection<&dyn Stringable>` for `StaticCollection`, just your chosen interface will probably cause issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how `StaticCollection` is implemented, but it is technically possible:

```
impl<'a> Collection<&'a dyn Stringable> for StaticCollection {
    fn add(&mut self, v: &'a dyn Stringable) {
        
    }
    fn get_all(&self) -> &Vec<&'a dyn Stringable> { 
        panic!()
    }
}
```

However `StaticCollection` must be created with `&dyn Stringable` items.
For example ([Link to playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=572990b8fbcd4032f387b4ba7acdd2e5)):

```
fn main() {
    let mut vs: &mut Collection<&dyn Stringable> = &mut StaticCollection { 
        v: vec![&0,&1,&2]
    };
    for v in vs.get_all() {
        println!("{}", v.string());
    }
}

struct StaticCollection {
    v: Vec<&'static dyn Stringable>,
}

impl<'a> Collection<&'a dyn Stringable> for StaticCollection {
    fn add(&mut self, v: &'a dyn Stringable) {
        
    }
    fn get_all(&self) -> &Vec<&'a dyn Stringable> { 
        &self.v
    }
}
```

Note that we are generic over the `'a` lifetime which is for the **items** of the `Vec`, but because the trait (as it is defined) requires `get_all` to return a `&Vec` borrowed from `self`, it is not possible to "transform" the `Vec`. So if you define `StaticCollection { v: Vec<&i8> }` (or `Vec<i8>`, `get_all` can not be implemented (without "leaking" a new `Vec`, which is probably not what you want).

The full lifetimes of `get_all` are actually:

```
fn get_all<'s>(&'s self) -> &'s Vec<&'a ...>
```

A word of warning: `dyn Trait` can get you into really tight corners with the compiler and borrow checker.
You might also want to checkout [this blog post](http://lukaskalbertodt.github.io/2018/08/03/solving-the-generalized-streaming-iterator-problem-without-gats.html) about "type families" which explores similar concepts.